# Sql server report alignment to center of web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, sql-server, reporting

I am using SQL Server Reporting service for reports and displaying it with Report viewer control.
It is displaying the report on left side of the page. I want it to be center aligned.

I tried Following things but it didn't worked out.

1. Wrapping Report viewer control in `div` or `table` and make it center aligned.
2. Zoom mode of Report viewer Control.

So please give me some solution for making it center aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<div align="center">

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" DocumentMapWidth="100%"

    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" PromptAreaCollapsed="True"

    ShowToolBar="False" Width="1100px" Height="100%">

    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

</div>
```

**OR With JQUERY:**

```
$('#ReportViewer1_fixedTable tbody tr').attr("align", "center");
```

**OR Server-Side:**

```
ReportPageSettings rst = rptVwr.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings();
            if (rptVwr.ParentForm.Width > rst.PaperSize.Width)
            {
                int vPad = (rptVwr.ParentForm.Width - rst.PaperSize.Width) / 2;
                rptVwr.Padding = new Padding(vPad, 1, vPad, 1);
            }
```

[Adjustment with heigh and width]

Hope its helpful.